# Symfony 2.1 FOSUser translate error messages

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I am using the following code to get all the errors in a form:

```
  // get all the errors in the form in an array
  public static function getErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form) {
    $errors = array();

    // actual errors
    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
        $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
    }

    // find children that are not valid
    if ($form->count()>0) {
        foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
            if (!$child->isValid()) { 
                $errors[$child->getName()] = formHelper::getErrorMessages($child);
            }
        }
    }
```

That works. The only issue is for FOSUser: I've defined my validation group and the errors aren't getting translated. Instead of getting "The password is too short" I am getting "fos_user.password.short". The issue is with the line:

```
$errors[] = $error->getMessage();
```

That does not translate the error. Anybody could help me out figure out this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use translator service to translate messages
Try this:

```
public function getFormErrorsAssoc(FormInterface $form) {
    $errors = array();                                                                                                                                   
    /* @var \Symfony\Component\Form\FormError $error*/                                                                                                   
    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {                                                                                                     
        $message = $this->translator->trans($error->getMessageTemplate(), $error->getMessageParameters(), 'validators');
        if ($message) {
            $errors[$key] = $message;
        }
    }
    if ($form->hasChildren()) {
        /* @var FormInterface $child*/
        foreach ($form->getChildren() as $child) {
            $label = $child->getAttribute('label') ? : $child->getName();
            if (!$child->isValid()) {
                $errors[$label] = $this->getFormErrorsAssoc($child);
            }
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```